# Ошибка использования global перед присванием переменных в двух if-ах

Tags: python-3.8

в общем, такой код, мучался, перепробовал разные варианты
не помогло, обращаюсь к вам

```
    global gemoji
    if results1[14] == 'male':
        gemoji = ''
    elif results1[14] == 'female':
        gemoji = ''
```

Вывод при её использовании:

`NameError: name 'gemoji' is not defined`

Что делать? Как исправить? При необходимости скину весь код.

Comment: На какой строке возникает ошибка?

Comment: на строке использования переменной

Comment: Во-первых, в показанном вами коде переменная нигде не используется. Во-вторых, это означает, что `results1[14]` не равен ни male, ни female, и переменная не создалась

Comment: спасибо, через пару минут, пока else поставил и все работает

Comment: спасибо, благодаря вам все работает как нужно